# Why do requests not timeout?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have ASP.NET WebApi2 application hosted in IIS (in Azure Cloud Service, if that matters here). I have set global request timeout in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="60" />
...
</system.web>
```

Yet when I look at currently running requests of worker process in IIS Manager, I can see many requests running (stuck) for hours:
[image: long running requests in IIS worker process]

How can this be?

And yes, I know I shall resolve the primary reason why some requests get stuck, but I thought timeout is good failsafe - but if requests never timeout, they eventually eat up some queue and application start returning 503s.

Application is in Release mode, running on remote server (not localhost).

Comment: There's no way to evaluate why this is happening to you without determining the root cause first.

Comment: You also need to check if you hit false positives in IIS Manager. Capture a hang dump of the worker process `w3wp.exe` and analyze the actual requests in it.